# how i can make the last one of breadcrumbs unclickable (with href)

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce

How I can make the last one of breadcrumbs unclickable (with href)

```xml
<ol class="breadcrumb" itemscope >
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a href="${breadcrumbValue.url}" title="{l s='Home Page'}" itemprop="item">
        </a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
    </li>
```

Thanks

Comment: You should make sure you are considering accessibility for users who might be leveraging a screen-reader-- if the link is reporting as a link with an href but no action occurs on click, that will be confusing.  Perhaps as an alternative you could simply render the last breadcrumb as a styled `<span>`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do would be `preventDefault`. It will stop the request from initiating.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("a");
elem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Hello click me</a>
```

Comment: Upvoting because, due to the magic of jQuery, this solution meets the user requirements of preventing interaction for both click _and_ for keyboard navigation.  However, please do remember that accessibility concerns may still remain-- for a user with a screen reader to encounter something indicated as a link that doesn't actually do anything may be confusing.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you, the person should also clearly tell the user that this `link` is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Using [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) you can make any element not receive clicks.

```css
.noclick {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="noclick">
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('I was clicked')">You can't click me</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="alert('I was clicked')">You can click me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that there are accessibility considerations with this.  First of all, you want a user using a screen-reader to not have the link indicated as a link if they cannot click it.  However, more importantly in this particular instance, it will not work for keyboard users-- using the keyboard, I can focus this link by tabbing and trigger it with the enter key and the alert will show. `pointer-events` _only_ suppress the mouse/pointer, _not_ the keyboard.

Comment: thanks   but  I have 4 dynamically generate tab
and I want to make the last one unclickable

Comment: I don't think that's much of an issue, since this is breadcrumbs and will redirect to the same page you are on already.

Comment: If it wasn't an issue to have the link triggered by a user why would the poster be asking the question in the first place?

Comment: He did ask unclickable, not untriggerable. Your concerns are valid though, and I myself would simply use a `<span>` instead.